# Solutions to a Modular Congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to find all integer solutions to the modular congruence $5x^7+x^2+2x \equiv 2\pmod {28}$

I broke it up into 2 cases: that is $\pmod 2,\pmod 7$.

Using the laws of congruence and Fermat's Little Theorem I got:

$5x^7+x^2+2x \equiv x\equiv1\pmod 2$

and

$5x^7+x^2+2x \equiv x^2+7x\pmod 2$

but I am not sure how to use this result I got. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Stop cheating on your Math 135 assignments! I will quote that on the first page of this assignment it says "Do not look up full or partial solutions on the Internet or in printed sources."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

You should break it up into $\pmod 4$ and $\pmod 7$.

That said, you are progressing in nearly the right way.

Notice that $5x^7+x^2+2x \equiv x^2+7x \equiv x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$ from Fermat's Little Theorem. .

Also , $\pmod 4$ can be devided into two cases, when $x$ is odd and when $x$ is even.

If $x$ is even, note that $2x, 5x^7, x^2$ are all divisible by $4$.

If $x$ is odd, note that $x^2+2x+5x^7 \equiv 7x+1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.